# git submodule update --init is returning blank

Tags: git, bash, minecraft

I followed two sets of instructions:
https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/cloning-building-and-compiling-the-spigot-source/
https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/spigot/browse/README.md

But my issue comes after the line:

```
git submodule update --init
```

According to the instructions, after I run the above command, I need to "wait for it to finish downloading" except that nothing downloads. It just returns immediately after pressing enter with no messages at all.

I googled some about how "git submodule update --init" returns blank, but I can't seem to apply that knowledge to my situation.

Here is my terminal output:

```
minecraft@localhost:~/testserver$ git clone https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/scm/spigot/spigot.git
Cloning into 'spigot'...
remote: Counting objects: 14823, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5480/5480), done.
remote: Total 14823 (delta 12828), reused 11073 (delta 9328)
Receiving objects: 100% (14823/14823), 2.97 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (12828/12828), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

minecraft@localhost:~/testserver$ cd spigot/

minecraft@localhost:~/testserver/spigot$ git submodule update --init

minecraft@localhost:~/testserver/spigot$ ./applyPatches.sh
Rebuilding Forked projects....
./applyPatches.sh: line 40: cd: ../Bukkit: No such file or directory
./applyPatches.sh: line 11: cd: /home/minecraft/testserver/spigot/Bukkit: No such file or directory
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/spigot': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
fatal: repository 'Bukkit' does not exist
./applyPatches.sh: line 20: cd: /home/minecraft/testserver/spigot/Spigot-API: No such file or directory
Resetting Spigot-API to Bukkit...
error: Could not remove config section 'remote.upstream'
fatal: ambiguous argument 'upstream/upstream': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
  Applying patches to Spigot-API...
Resolve operation not in progress, we are not resuming.
Applying: POM Changes
fatal: sha1 information is lacking or useless (pom.xml).
Repository lacks necessary blobs to fall back on 3-way merge.
Cannot fall back to three-way merge.
Patch failed at 0001 POM Changes
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   /home/minecraft/testserver/spigot/.git/rebase-apply/patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
  Something did not apply cleanly to Spigot-API.
  Please review above details and finish the apply then
  save the changes with rebuildPatches.sh
```

Comment: Looks like a problem the devs will have to fix IMO. There are no submodules in that repo as far as I can see.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Thank you! I'm such a noob!

Comment: The submodule entries were deleted in revision {{6b9c932ab4f6ac051fab4f2f60cc7bf4949216c7}} on {{Wed Nov 26 08:27:08 2014 +1100}}. So... those directions have been wrong for a *very* long time.